# Why does time flow more slowly on the ground than on a mountain?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, potential-energy, time-dilation

I'm reading the book *The Order of Time* by 'Carlo Rovelli', which says that time flows more slowly on the ground than on a mountain. It also says that the presence of matter changes how time flows, and specifically that it flows more slowly near the surface of the earth. Why is this?

Comment: It seems like you're really asking, "why is gravitational time dilation a thing?" (although I realize you probably didn't know to use that terminology).  That's a pretty general question that isn't particularly well suited for physics SE.  I suggest Googling "gravitational time dilation explained" (or, maybe just start with "time dilation explained") or the like, and, if, after reading some article or watching some videos on the topic, you have more questions, post those more specific questions here.

Comment: [Why can't I do this to get infinite energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178417/37364)

Comment: look up about gravitational time dilation and you will see the place where with more effect of gravity time flows more slowly and reduces with respect to the inverse square law

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The bigger the mass, the more time slows down](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52034/the-bigger-the-mass-the-more-time-slows-down-why-is-this) See also: [Why does gravity cause time dilation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/406718/226902), [Why does the flow of time slow down as curvature gets deeper?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/589543/226902), [Why does time slow down closer to a mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/134097/226902), [Carlo Rovelli's analogy of gravity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/610166/226902)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language we often use to describe time (like "time flowing") gives a misleading picture -- it makes it seem as though "time" is a thing that is moving. The modern view in physics is that time is more like a direction in 4 dimensional spacetime.

You've probably heard that gravity is due to the curvature of spacetime. This curvature also means that the direction of time is different in different places. For a rough analogy, consider the direction "up" at the North Pole and near the equator: something moving "up" near the equator hardly moves "up" at all relative to the North Pole. Similarly, the time direction is different near the Earth's surface (where spacetime is curved more by the Earth's mass) than it is high above the Earth's surface (where spacetime is curved less). The exact details are a little more complicated in the case of spacetime than of space, because the geometry of spacetime is different from that of space alone, but the upshot is that a clock on the surface seems slow when compared to a clock on the mountain. The difference is tiny though and it takes very sensitive atomic clocks to detect it.

Comment: I write my understanding: At the position where the gravity is bigger, the curvature of spacetime is bigger and time is slower; at the position where the gravity is smaller, the curvature of spacetime is smaller and time is faster. Is it right?

Comment: That's almost right. There is a direct relationship between spacetime curvature and time, but only an indirect relationship between spacetime curvature and gravitational acceleration. Clocks deeper in a gravitational potential well tick slower (when compared to clocks higher in the gravitational potential). This isn't quite the same as saying "gravity is stronger". For example, at the center of the Earth there would be no gravitational acceleration at all, but clocks would still be slower than on the surface of the Earth.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a question related to a thing called 'Time Dilation', predicted by Albert Einstein in the theory of Special Relativity. It basically says that if I was on earth and you were in space, for example, and you and me had a clock each (atomic clock) which were both showing the same time initially, and if you were to go close to the speed of light for a while, once you stop and when we both check our clocks, we would see that your clock would show a time that already elapsed on my clock. This means that your clock ticked *slower* and my clock ticked *relatively* faster. But, from your perspective, your clock ticked normally for you, and from my perspective, my clock ticked normally for me. But when we compare them, because you travelled faster than me relatively, your clock ticked slower.

Now, coming to your question specifically, time does tick slower on the ground than on a mountain. This is because of the difference in gravity acting on an object on ground (more gravity) and on an object on a mountain (less gravity). The rate at which time ticks also depends on gravity. If the gravity is more, time ticks slower and vice versa. That's why `time ticks slower on ground (higher gravitational acceleration) than on a mountain (lower gravitational acceleration).` But, the time dilation effect in such a case would be *very very tiny*, yet, it would still exist.

Comment: Gravitational time dilation doesn't depend on the local gravitational acceleration, though. For example, time dilation would be most extreme at the center of the Earth, even though the gravitational acceleration is zero there. It depends on the gravitational acceleration integrated between the two points you are comparing (i.e., the gravitational potential difference).